# Error 13 using MsgBox to display Range

Tags: excel, type-mismatch, vba

I'm running into a type mismatch at the 4th line of the following code:

```
If Intersect(rngBay6.Offset(10, 0), rngBay9.Offset(7, 0)) Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "No intersection"
Else
    MsgBox Intersect(rngBay6.Offset(10, 0), rngBay9.Offset(7, 0))
End If
```

`rngBay6` and `rngBay9` are both ranges that have a subset of each range intersect after the offset. I can not figure out what's wrong here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies, just found the error. Forgot to use `.Address`. Code should be as so:

```
If Intersect(rngBay6.Offset(10, 0), rngBay9.Offset(7, 0)) Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "No intersection"
Else
    MsgBox Intersect(rngBay6.Offset(10, 0), rngBay9.Offset(7, 0)).Address
End If
```